# Make objects fall slower when in a certain area - sprite kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, gravity

The title says it all, I want all the objects within a certain area to fall slower than the rest of the objects, I am well aware that I can change the gravity of the physics world, but I need only some of the objects to fall slowly, so that wasn't a option. Also, this is all to simulate objects in water, so if there is any better way to do that, that would be appreciated.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase your `friction` or your `linearDamping` / `angularDamping` on your `physicsBody` to add resistance to bodies.  You can also change the `speed` setting of your `physicsWorld` if you want everything to slow down (Which would work in an under water setting)

Comment: how would they know when an object was in water or not?

Comment: beyond the scope of his question

Comment: Thx for the help

Comment: I was going to suggest using gravity fields and changing the objects' bitMasks when necessary so that they are affected by different gravities, but to simulate water, this would be the most realistic solution, as in water you are still in Earth's gravity.